# What's Marlin DRM used for if we have CENC, MSE and EME?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, drm, mpeg-dash

Lately I've been reading about the different technologies involved in video streaming security, and I have a doubt about the Marlin DRM.

As I understand, it's a intermediate "DRM" so that the client doesn't need to integrate every other DRM. But isn't that what the Common Encryption (CENC) does? And then we have the MSE and EME extensions to handle the video in the code, so... what's the Marlin used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You do not need to consider Marlin, assuming you are only interested in HTTP streaming to the browser.

Some brief background:

[Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) (MSE) controls client side video playback using JavaScript.

[Encrypted Media Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/) (EME) is a standard API for your web application (such as client side javascript) to interact with a Content Decryption Module (CDM).

The CDM is the client side implementation of the secret sauce that is the DRM solution. It will be provided by the underlying platform, and your application interacts with it using the EME API.

Common Encryption (CENC) is an ISO/IEC standard (23001-7:2016) "specified to enable multiple digital rights and key management systems (DRMs) to access the same common encrypted file or stream".

Marlin is just another DRM solution, and is used in certain environments (like Sony devices, InFlight entertainment and the UK YouView platform) but not in any mainstream browser.

Like PrimeTime, Playready and Widevine, Marlin can use CENC media. You prepare the content once, and depending on what CDM is available you retrieve the license/key using the supported DRM. You will probably have to support multiple DRM solutions if you have a public facing application. This is still an area with a lot of change, but Playready and Widevine will get you support on modern versions of IE/Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

There is talk that Safari/iOS will support CENC media with the Fairplay DRM soon. Perhaps this year (2016). This will probably not be MPEG-DASH, but HLS. However, HLS will apparently support using ISO BMFF video fragments instead of the MPEG TS currently used.

Answer (score 1):

CENC  just describes how to protect the file. Specifically how to encrypt it in a standard way so that it can be decrypted by any player that has the key. This is only half of the DRM equation. The other half is authentication, key management, distribution and in memory protection.

Comment: so according to your answer, the scheme is more or less like: `(Different DRM systems) --> CENC --> Marlin --> browser (MSE/EME) --> user watches video`??

Answer (score 0):

Most content protection systems have two key parts, as szatmary notes:

- a mechanism to take the raw data (e.g. video data) and encrypt it
  using some key
- a secure mechanism to store the key for the encrypted content and to transport it securely to a client when it is determined they are entitled to view the content

The reason CENC is useful it that traditionally, because different devices support different DRM systems, you have to encrypt a single video differently for multipole different target devices.

CENC provides a standard encryption method so the encryption step is the same no matter which DRM system is being used.

Combining CENC with MPEG DASH packaging (an mechanism to group multiple bit rate version of a video along with an index or manifest, allowing the client to choose the best bit rate for the current network conditions) allows the video be encrypted once only (or more accurately you need to encrypt each bit rate version of in the DASH package) and the information for the DRM key exchange between the client and the DRM server be included in the packaged stream for multiple different types of DRM's together.

As an aside, I don't think Marlin is really an intermediate DRM as you ask in your question - i.e. it is a DRM mechanism itself rather than a front to other DRM's like Wideivine, FairPlay, Playready etc.